# Override tax calculation management in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to override the way magento calculates taxes.

I need to change a customer's tax class on the fly, when he changes his addresses o fills a VAT number.

To do this i figured out that rewriting the Customer method getTaxClassId() was enough but it is not. I found out that to make its calculations Magento uses the customer's tax class and also his group's tax class.

To calculate the right rate, group and customer tax class must be the same.

The problem is that I can't override group's tax class ID because when you do

Mage::getModel("customer/group")->getTaxClassId($groupID)

I can't determine what customer it is referencing to.

So maybe I can try another approach: I was thinking to rewrite the tax rule calculation class. The goal is to redefine tax rules on a Product Tax Class, CUSTOMER Tax Class but I'm unable to understand where Magento does this.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!